# Solar Water Heater issue

Tags: water, water-heater, solar

[image]I have a solar hot water heater, and one of the pipes in the crawl space starting leaking.  I have shut off the pipes thru crawl space and just running off the electric for now.
The pipe with the run off outside is still dripping water and it has been almost a week.  Does anyone know if it is still water coming from the pipes draining.....or do I have another issue???
Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Where is the pipe leaking? Which pipe is it; the send to the panels, or the return? Are you going to drain the pipes anyway for winter (presuming northern part of Northern Hemisphere)? Could you post a picture?

Comment: The original leak is from a pipe going/coming from the solar roof panels.  The one dripping is outside the house.  I am not sure how to attach a photo...and I am in Florida - usually don't have a freeze issue..haha

Comment: You've added a photo, but what does it show?

Comment: the pipe coming from the house and dripping, it is from the pipes that run into the roof

Comment: Where does this pipe go? It's obviously not part of the water heating circuit. (A diagram might really help.)